# How do you create an Expression of an enum from its type and the name of one of its fields?

Tags: c#, enums, expression-trees

Had a hard time finding what I'm trying to do and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309139/how-to-apply-generic-expression-trees-code-that-works-well-on-integers-to-enums) was the closest I could find.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855881/create-instance-of-unknown-enum-with-string-value-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) won't work as I don't know the integer value of the enum, I only know its name.  Given the following code:

```cs
public enum Foo 
{
    Row = 0,
    Column = 20, // This is why the second post won't work, I only know the name "Column"
    None = 30
}

public static class ExpressionGetter
{
    public static Expression GetExpression(Type type, string name)
    {
        // Not sure what I should do here. I want an expression object for Foo.Row
    }
}

void Main()
{
   var expression = ExpressGetter.GetExpression(typeof(Foo), "Row");
}
```

Later in my application, I am building expression trees to generate LINQ queries and I know the type of the `enum` and name of the `enum` and now I want to create an `Expression.Constant` of it or if there's another way to do this, I'd like to know how.

I want at the end an expression that looks like this:

`Foo.Row`

I've tried:

```
Expression.Property(null, enumType, name)
```

But it does not work.  Results in

> ArgumentException: Property 'Row' is not defined for type 'Foo'
>   Parameter name: propertyName

which makes sense because it's a struct not an object.

So I'm not sure how to build the Expression `Foo.Row` given the enum type `Foo` and the name as a string.

Comment: Are you trying to extract the string value from the enum? Something like, `Print(Foo.Row)` prints out `"Row"`? Or are you trying to get the integer value, like `0, 20, 30`?

Comment: This question is confusing and I get a feeling that it has a lot of irrelavant information while required info is missing. Do you simply want to get enum value from it's int?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/135230). Instead of telling us what you're doing, tell us what your goal is because “create an expression of an enum from its type and name” isn't a goal.

Comment: If you're using `null` for the `expression` argument, `MyFoo` has to be a static property, but since you're using `obj.MyFoo` it doesn't appear as though you want to test a static property...

Comment: `Expression.Constant(Foo.Row, typeof(Foo));`

Comment: I won't know the constant at runtime, as my question states, the pieces of information I know are the type of enum and a string of the enum's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enum value is a static field of the enum type. If you only have the name of the enum value as a string, the second version is what you're looking for. But you could also do Enum.Parse() with the first version.

```
Expression.Constant(Foo.Row, typeof(Foo));

//  Or any other string that's valid
var name = "Row";
MemberExpression.Field(null, typeof(Foo), name);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I won't know the constant at runtime.

Comment: @akousmata What *will* you know at runtime? Your question says *"I only know the name "Column""*. Do you actually mean you only know the value `20`? If you know the name of the enum value as a string, my second suggestion works fine.

Comment: Correct, I know the name of the enum value as a string. Testing your suggestion now.

Comment: So I was on the right path with `Expression.Property(null, enumType, name)` and just didn't realize that I needed to use `.Field` instead.  This option didn't occur to me, thanks for the help.

Comment: @akousmata Right. Just needed to keep trial-and-erroring it.

Answer (score 0):

More or less like this:

```
public enum EnumerationTest
{
    A, B, C
}

public class ClassTest
{
    public EnumerationTest Test { get; set; }
}

public static Expression PropertyExpression()
{
    // Think of this like a lambda (p) => p.Test == Enumeration.A
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ClassTest), "p"); 
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Test");
    var value = (EnumerationTest)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumerationTest), "A");
    var constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(EnumerationTest));

    return Expression.Equal(property, constant);
 }
```

You generally are using a lot of reflection and string parsing when doing Expression trees. At least that's what I have found in my experience

Comment: I don't know the enumeration constant at runtime, otherwise, this would be a trivial thing to do, see my edits.

Comment: So are you dealing with two properties? Or a property or a variable? Either way, just swap out the Expression.Constant with Expression.PropertyOrField

Comment: You'd assemble the second the same way as I assembled the first one. You have some expression, it has some property of some type.

Comment: I apologize, I see the confusion that my question originally caused, but have updated it.  `var constant = Expression.Constant(EnumerationTest.A, typeof(EnumerationTest));` is the issue.  I don't know that the constant is `EnumerationTest.A`.  I know `typeof(EnumerationTest)` and that the name (as a string) of the enumeration value is `A` but that is all.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but that is more or less what I had at one point and the result is the expression ends up being only the value (i.e. `Row` instead of `Foo.Row`).  Ed Plunkett provided an answer that is working.

Comment: The 'Row' value might still work. The expression should know the type. I vaguely remember building expressions that worked that had similar eccentricity. I'm not sure you can go 100% by what shows up in the intellisense.